# DDR Supernova unlock Pizza Box

Tags: ps2, dance-dance-revolution

What are the criteria to unlock the Pizza Box Stellar Joint?

Do I have to get 100% on all other planets or is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

You need to unlock and complete the ten previous Stellar Joints in order to unlock the Pizza Box Stellar Joint.